# Changing extension of a program

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008

I downloaded Visual C++ express edition 2008 but the problem is the file doesn't has any extension. I don't know how to run it inorder to install it. Is there a way I can execute this program for installing it on my computer..

I would be very thankful to you..

Comment: Is it an image file by any chance? If it is then either mount it to a disc or virtually mount it with software.

Comment: No its not cuz it is not working with PowerISO.

Comment: Is it a corrupt download then? Maybe try re-downloading it? I don't know what else to suggest, sorry.

Comment: Please People there is no need to vote down this question.. If someone doesn't know something and asks a question don't dislike unless the question is controversial type

Comment: The downvotes are probably 'cos it's quite a hard question to answer as is - there could be any number of reasons why you have downloaded an invalid file. Also it's not really a C++/C/Visual Studio question, it's a broken download question...

Comment: People downvote questions that they think were poorly asked, or that aren't appropriate for the site. I don't usually do it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2008 Express edition is available in multiple download forms from [this address](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2008-editions/express) @ Microsoft. The default Visual C++ download is a over-the-web installer (vcsetup.exe). the full download as an ISO mountable or burnable to a disc is also available.

And the ISO is about 784.9 MB if you go that route, just to help you assess if you obtained a bogus download and need to refetch.